# Ubuntu 12.04 rename folders in mnt & media

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, shared-folders, media

Installing a new VPN on a new workstation and it has been a year since I did my last Virtualbox setup.  Everything works but I don't like how the shared folders in media are labeled as `sf_folder`.  I was curious to know can I rename these folders or would it cause issues?  I didn't see a solution or any documentation on it from a search.  Setup is now Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 running Virtualbox.  This may be another question but after the initial install and setup of shared folders and Guest Additions I only see a folder in `media` and not `mnt`.  I can get a shared folder in `mnt` with `sudo ln -sf /media/folder /mnt/` but I don't know yet if there's a better way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sf_` is alwasy prepended by VirtualBox to indicate that it's a shared folder. This is done by a vbox service, part of the Guest Additions. You can bind the shared folder directory to another of your choice in `mtab` if you desire.

Use this to open the mtab file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/mtab
```

In the mtab file enter a new line at the bottom.  The format you want to use is:

```
/real/folder/location  /where/youwantit/toshow bind rw 0 0
```

Here's an example from one of mine:

```
/media/sf_IBM /opt/ibm bind rw 0 0
```

It's standard practice to hit [enter] when you've finished your edit so there is a new line entry at the end of the file.

Comment: Could you expand your answer on how to perform this "bind mount"?

Comment: Why are you proposing to use `/etc/mtab`? `/etc/fstab` is the file where configuration happens.

Comment: if he makes the edits in fstab, ubuntu will error when starting.  The sf_ object to mount isn't available until the vbox services start, which is after fstab.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to add a folder in the `mnt` location from the `media` location without having `sf_`.

I used this code:

`sudo mount --bind /media/sf_folder /mnt/folder`

Comment: While your command will work, it will only work for your existing session. When you reboot, the bind will be lost and you'll have to manually enter the command again.